# Load scikit-learn library without installing it

Tags: python, installation, load, package, scikit-learn

**My problem :**
I have a script that needs scikit learn 0.17 library.
I have to deploy an application which use this script on a server on which I am not allowed to install anything. However I know that scikit learn 0.15 is installed on the server.
I know there is some stuff about this topic on stackoverflow, but I’m a noob and I’m stuck.

**My Question :**
Anyone see how it could be possible to load scikit learn 0.17 package without installing it?

Answer (score 0):

Check that site:
https://try.jupyter.org/
It contains interpreter with numpy, scikit and another goods. Upload your code and enjoy.

Comment: I need to run this script on a Hadoop Server. So I do not think Jupyter is good.